# Why does the zero-inflated Poisson model in R's mgcv package only display one set of coefficients?

Tags: r, interpretation, generalized-additive-model, count-data, zero-inflation

I am using the `mgcv` package in R to build a Generalized Additive Model via the `gam()` function with the `ziP()` family call. My model is called via the following code:

```
model1 <- gam(outcome ~ metric + year + elevation +
            s(longitude,latitude) + s(Location_ID,bs='re'),
          offset = log(population),
          family=ziP,
          data=Data)
```

The variable `outcome` is Poisson-distributed with excess zero counts.

`summary(model1)` returns the following output:

```
Family: Zero inflated Poisson(-2.235,1.683) 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
outcome ~ metric + year + elevation + s(longitude, latitude) + 
    s(Location_ID, bs = "re")

Parametric coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.457e+02  1.006e+01 -14.488   <2e-16 ***
metric       3.479e-01  1.548e-01   2.247   0.0246 *  
year         7.078e-02  4.985e-03  14.199   <2e-16 ***
elevation    7.505e-05  2.412e-04   0.311   0.7557    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                          edf Ref.df  Chi.sq p-value    
s(longitude,latitude) 25.3773   27.7 377.027  <2e-16 ***
s(Location_ID)         0.1729    1.0   0.197   0.283    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Deviance explained = 52.6%
-REML = 1884.6  Scale est. = 1         n = 1282
```

I have run ZIP and ZINB models previously using other packages, though these were not GAMs. Other packages give the coefficients of the count portion and zero-inflated portion of the model. The gam only provides one set of parametric coefficients, and I am unsure if these are coefficients for the count or zero-inflated portion of the model.

It is important to know which coefficients these are, particularly because the directionality of the relationship between independent and dependent variables are often opposite in the two portions of the model. Without knowing which portion of the model I am looking at, I cannot draw conclusions.

Comment: A general comment: using an identity link is very uncommon here.

Comment: The identity link is the only one that is supported via the `ziP()` family call in `mgcv`. But you're right, I hadn't noticed. I figured log link would be the default.

Comment: You are right. I now went through the docu - not sure what model is actually estimated.

Comment: This post by Gavin Simpson: https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/05/04/compare-mgcv-with-glmmtmb/

shows that you fit the zi portion of the model by adding another formula equation: `~ spp * mined`, but I don't see this in the documentation either.

Comment: I also get the error: "`Error in gam(list(outcome ~ metric + year + s(longitude, latitude) +  : 
  incorrect number of linear predictors for family`" when trying to implement the second formula.

Comment: There are two zero-augmented/inflated models in {mgcv}; the `ziP()` family and the `ziplss()` family. Only the latter allows you to model the zero augmentation part (noting that the `ziplss()` model is actually a hurdle model.) The reason for the identity link is due to the way the model is parameterised internally. The `ziP()` family includes a constant zero inflation term, another intercept if you will, in the inflation part. The estimates values of which are noted in the the summary output in the first line after `Family:`. I'd need to check the code to figure out exactly what these are tho